# Join 3 or more CSV's that all contain the same first columns

Tags: csv, join, miller

I am looking to join 3 (or More) CSV's into 1 csv.
Each CSV contains the same data in the first column. It will always be the same in the first column.
for example column 1, line 1 will be the same in all 3+ csv's, Column 1, line 2 will be the same in all 3 csv's....etc.

Sample data

csv_1:

```
date, a
1,b
2,c
3,d
```

csv_2:

```
date,t
1,h
2,j
3,k
```

csv_3:

```
date, q
1,w
2,e
3,r
```

Output CSV:

```
date,a,t,q
1,b,h,w
2,c,j,e
3,d,k,r
```

I was hoping to achieve this with miller. It works great for combining 2 csv's with this command:

mlr --csv join -u -j Date -f csv_1 csv_2 > output.csv

sadly if i add another csv like this:
mlr --csv join -u -j Date -f csv_1 csv_2 csv_3 > output.csv
It will add 2 more columns to the end of the file.

Can this be achieved with miller?

I have googled this problem and cant find a solution.
Tried the join above but it only works for 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `then`

```
mlr --csv join -j date -f 01.csv then join -j date -f 02.csv 03.csv
```

and you get

| date | t | a | q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | h | b | w |
| 2 | j | c | e |
| 3 | k | d | r |

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I forgot to mention in my post. I can get it to work with your suggestion or even dropping each result into a temp file, then running the command again, and so on and so on. Also forgot to mention that I. Using windows batch file and mlr.exe to run this. In the windows batch file I have a string that figures out all of the variables of the needed CSV files. For example. Csv_1, csv_6, csv_8, csv3. I was hoping to apply that variable into the MLR request. For example. mlr --csv join -u -j Date -f %allcsvs% > output.csv

Comment: the mlr syntax is that one, you cannot write a simple list of csv. You could build a var "then join -j date -f 02.csv then join -j date -f 03.csv ..." and at the end the last. Or you could build a for loop working with pairs of files and producing a temporary file at each cycle

Comment: Yep I was considering the pairs of variables as a possibility. That's actually when I decided to come here, because there will be 8 possibilities. It could be CSV 1 and 5. Or CSV 3 and 7, or CSV 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. there's are a huge amount of possible pairs. Would be a pain to write out or think about it. Guess I might have to consider this route

Comment: with a simple loop, you solve it

Comment: Yea I might just give that a go. It is also worth mentioning that all CSV files have the same order. Just different columns so It doesn't have to be miller or to 'join'. I can't combine column 1,2 on each CSV and them remove the column 1 duplicates or something like that. Don't know if that might be quicker or longer than doing a loop with all the conditions.

Comment: @mysql I have added a new answer, but I work in linux shell. THere is very easy to do it

Answer (score 1):

If all CSV files have the same order and you want to combine column 1,2 on each CSV and them remove the column 1 duplicates, in the Unix shell you can run:

```
paste -d ',' *.csv | mlr --csv label ref_date then cut -x -r -f "^date"
```

| ref_date | a | t | q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | h | w |
| 2 | c | j | e |
| 3 | d | k | r |

Comment: Yep this could work. Is there any alternative to paste for windows? Or is there somewhere I can get paste for windows like I have with MLR.exe and sed.exe, awk.exe etc.

Comment: Ok got gnucoreutils and tried this.

Comment: Ref date column is good. Next column (a) isn't displaying right. It has a combination displayed like this "a'date". All of the data is also displaying the same in this column.  3rd column is good also. 4th column just contains date_2 and all of the dates, 5th column is good

Comment: @mysql in my pc it works (https://i.imgur.com/PDROSNP.png). Could you share your input files?

Comment: Not at pc at the moment. I can tell you that each column has values like 33.2. Column header is something like "column 1: (data/details)". Date column is "29/09/2023 15:45". I am calling the Csvs with the a variable -  "%variable%"_*.csv. instead of just *.csv. everything else the same